# How to periodically disable a Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel

I want to disable my Laravel app for night and make it accessible at daytime.
A catch-all route in my route file, activated by a binary variable, would be my way of doing this. Is there a ready-to-use or just more elegant way to do this?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/configuration#maintenance-mode and cron?

Comment: Using middleware is good idea to do so.

Make a middleware , that includes the current time matching with day start time and day end time , add it inside condition if true then return next request else return some view
Register middleware inside kernal
and add this middleware to routes

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on the server through **Cron Job**.

The first Cron Job limit activates the **maintenance** mode at the time you want

The second limit job is responsible for disabling the **maintenance** mode

You can specify when each of the limit jobs will be executed

Please read these two links below

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/configuration#maintenance-mode
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling